# Angular shared module

Tags: angular

One general query regarding the usage of shared components in angular 5.
For example, I have a shared component which has some functionality.
I got two modules in which this module need to be shared. For one module, one validation need to be performed and an input is expected in shared module. So, to achieve this, do we need to handle this shared component?

Any other way to achieve this?

Please advise.

Comment: can you please elaborate this, what i am getting from this  question that you have three modules out of which 1 is shared between two and you want to pass data to another module after validating from first module  so why your are making this complex just create a shared service and perform validation and set  the data to shared service member based upon validation

Comment: Thanks Sunny for the reply.The validation is happening in shared module as per the flow.But my requirement is ,the validation should not happen in for one of the module which is using this shared component.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that You need validation in one of the parent component and not in some other parent component

Since the shared component is a child component, it can accept @input from the parent component, from reusability and readability point of you, I will suggest you do something like this,

Parent component logic

```
<shared-component [validate]="A Boolean Passed from parent compoent"></shared-component>
```

Shared Component logic

```
@input()validate: Boolean
```

if the parents component sends validate as true you can add validation logic to the fields, if it sends false you can ignore the validation.

Hope this helps, please correct me if I am wrong.